# Why does this String.equals() not work?

Tags: java, string, udp, equals

I'm trying to build a simple `UDPServer` and `UDPClient`. A String comparison doesn't work.
Here's what I got so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class UDPSender
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9877);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            boolean weiter = true;

             do {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                  InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                  int port = receivePacket.getPort();

                  /*I'm trying to make the if()-statement true, but the program always enters the else()-clause, no matter what I do.*/
                  if("Shutdown".equals(sentence)) {
                      weiter = false;
                      String bye = ("Auf Wiedersehen! Verbindung wird gekappt...");
                      sendData = bye.getBytes();
                      DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                              new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                      serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                      serverSocket.close();
                  } else {                    
                      String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                      sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                      DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                              new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                      serverSocket.send(sendPacket);                      
                  }
               } while(weiter);
      }
}
```

And this is the client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class UDPClient{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
       BufferedReader inFromUser =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
       InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
       byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
       byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

       //Look, I'm explicitly sending Shutdown, too!            
       String sentence = "Shutdown";
       sendData = sentence.getBytes();
       DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9877);
       clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
       DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
       clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
       String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
       System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
       clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I would be happy if both would work on the same computer for now, but after this String issue is fixed, I need to get more PCs involved. Tried about every solution suggested in other similar questions on stackoverflow and anything google listed on the first three pages, nothing worked for me. Can you see something I can't?

Comment: Have you checked that `sentence` isn't padded with nul characters, spaces (or other non-printables)?

Comment: Take a debugger, run the code in it, put a breakpoint to the comparison, check what's exactly in the variable.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, your suspicion turned out to be correct. There were nul characters. ^^; Reimeus' solution fixed it for me. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you rely on the fixed size buffer `byte[] ... = new byte[1024]` to send and receive packets.

My advice is to send only the data you really need:

```
String sentence = "Shutdown";
byte[] sendData = sentence.getBytes();
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9877);
```

... and create the `String` instance on the server side accordingly to the length obtained from the `receivePacket.getLength()` method:

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

---

See also [`public String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-)